# c programming - Why this simple calculator using switch doesn't work

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am trying to figure out why this almost identical codes behave differently.

The first one runs fine (here the scanf operator is placed before the scanf operands)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        char operator;
        double first, second;

        printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *,): ");
        scanf("%c", &operator);

        printf("Enter two operands: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf", &first, &second);

        switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first + second);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%.1lf - %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first - second);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%.1lf * %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first * second);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%.1lf / %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first / second);
            break;
            // operator doesn't match any case constant
        default:
            printf("Error! operator is not correct");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Now, the second one doesn't (here the scanf operands are placed before the scanf operator)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
   int main() {
       char operator;
       double first, second;

       printf("Enter two operands: ");
       scanf("%lf %lf", &first, &second);

       printf("Enter an operator (+, -, *,): ");
       scanf("%c", &operator);

       switch (operator) {
       case '+':
           printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first + second);
           break;
       case '-':
           printf("%.1lf - %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first - second);
           break;
       case '*':
           printf("%.1lf * %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first * second);
           break;
       case '/':
           printf("%.1lf / %.1lf = %.1lf", first, second, first / second);
           break;
           // operator doesn't match any case constant
       default:
           printf("Error! operator is not correct");
       }
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `switch` statement.

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &operator);` (notice the addition of the `space`)

Comment: Thank you This added space made it work. I wonder why this was necessary depending on the order scanf was placed...

Answer (score -1):

When you typed in two numbers, you entered:

```
3.141 2.71828\n
```

Note the newline at the end.  The newline is not part of a double (`%lf`), so it did NOT get read out of the input buffer into `second`.  Instead, the newline(`\n`) stayed in the input buffer.

The next `scanf` is for a character (`%c`).  And which character did it get?  It got the Newline!

So your variable `operand` has character `\n` in it.

To fix it, make your scanfs:

```
scanf("%lf %lf ", &first, &second);
scanf("%c ", &operator);   // Note the extra space at the end of each format-string
```

Comment: There is a problem with space after the specifier... a space scans all whitespaces until a not-whitespace is encountered. The problem is that `"%c "` will execute __until__ you press anything else then a whitespace, because `scanf` will wait for anything else then a whitespace, and because lines are buffered, you have to also press enter. In short, it's better to just put a space before `%c`, `" %c"`, to let it just read the newline that is already buffered.

Comment: Great to know and thank you for helping me understand this but still i don't get why this extra space depends on the order the scanf is placed.